# Why are there so many sleeping tasks in PostgreSQL-Aurora?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm seeing a large number of sleeping tasks ([dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXwAp.png)) in a PostgreSQL-Aurora instance. What are they?

Please correct me if I'm wrong. First, **os.tasks** seem to be Linux processes (not threads) since they have a zombie state. Then the **blocked** tasks are those in the uninterruptible sleep state, and **sleeping** tasks are those in the interruptible sleep state.

Then the 1.3 K sleeping tasks are the preallocated DB processes ready to be woken up when a query arrives from a client connection? And the number is dynamically adjusted based on the connections? The **max_connections** for this instance type is 5000 [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Managing.html].